# Why don't servers deliver JS and CSS at the same time as HTML?

Tags: web-development, web, server

Since every time a web browser requests a page, we are almost certain that there are .css and .js files to be sent as well. Why do we wait for the browser to parse the DOM and discover those files before issuing a request for the CSS and JS files? The server has the HTML files and knows all the links to other resources. Why doesn't the server say *"Hei, you want foo.html? here you go, but you would need also foo.js and foo.css"*?
Has this been considered? What are the drawbacks of this solution?

It is not the browser, it a server implementation. Let's say IIS or Apache, pre-scans the html and discovers all the CSS and JS include in each specific html page.

Comment: Why do you mean *"by issuing a request for the CSS and JS files"*? You mean downloading them?

Comment: HTTP/2 solves this problem. Look it up.

Comment: Wouldn't that download the whole site?

Comment: @RibaldEddie no more extra round trips and render blocking requests in HTTP2? any particular part of HTTP2 I should look up?

Comment: *"here you go, but you would need also foo.js and foo.css"* - isn't that what the <script> and <link> tags are for?  How is the server supposed to magically know what files are needed?

Comment: `Why do we wait for the browser to parse the DOM and discover those files before issuing a request for the CSS and JS files?` -- How would the browser know otherwise?

Comment: You should put more context in your question. As it is now, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is the server who knows and it serves it to the browser.

Comment: @GrandmasterB why is it magic, doesn't the server have access to the html and knows where the pages it is serving?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova when a browser receives an HTML pages it starts parsing in, and when it encounters CSS or Javascript it stops and must request those files.

Comment: If the server were to send things just because they're linked in the page without your browser requesting them, that would be push technology. Pages have links to all kinds of files. Browsers request .css and .js because they need them to render the page but, for example, when you download an html page with wget it doesn't request .css or .js from the browser.

Comment: @mben: Actually, *when* the browser requests those files is an *implementation detail.*

Comment: @TulainsCórdova any CSS and JS included in an HTML must and will be requested

Comment: @RobertHarvey isn't CSS rendering blocking and a must for constructing the CSSOM?

Comment: Rendering the page and parsing the html aren't the same things.

Comment: @MBen I just ran `wget -q -U Mozilla -O apple.html http://www.apple.com` and it only downloaded the index.html file of the Apple website (which I named apple.html). No .css, .js or jpg etc.

Comment: *"Let's say IIS or Apache, pre-scans the html and discovers all the CSS and JS include in each specific html page."* That would cause every page downloaded be bloated with the inserted .css ans .js code that was stored as separate files in the browser. That would be like a waste of bandwidth. Although I'm sure there may be some obscure and little known or specialized browser that does just that.

Comment: @MBen: no, the server doesn't have access to the HTML. The server doesn't even know what HTML is. The server serves documents. It has absolutely not idea what those documents mean. They could be HTML, XHTML, XML, CSS, ECMAScript, JSON, PDF, MP3, AVI, JPEG, PNG, GIF, SVG, DOC, DOCX, XSD, `.jar`, `.exe`, `.zip`, `.rar`, `.7z`, `.iso`, Python, Ruby, some proprietary binary blob, or whatever.

Comment: @MBen: are you suggesting that the server should send all referenced documents without the client explicitly requesting them? So, what if I search something on Google, and I get 30000 results. Should the server send me all 30000 referenced sites? If not, why not? How does the server decide which references to send and which not?

Comment: @MBen And how does the server 'know' what files are supposed to be served up?  What about dynamic content?

Comment: @JörgWMittag You haven't done much web programming have you? [Server side includes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html) are a pretty common thing. There's no reason a server could not be made to understand html and include content based on that.

Comment: @8bittree: I would argue SSIs are a feature of a web framework, not a server. (A feature which may be integrated into a server, turning the server into a web framework.) But even so, understanding which files the server needs to compose in order to generate a response, and understanding which files the client needs in order to render a representation are two different things. E.g., if the site uses CSS media queries, the server would need to know the screen size of the client, or whether it is a text-to-speech renderer. It would need to know the result of every content negotiation beforehand.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I would argue that in the context of this question, whether SSIs are part of the web framework or the server program is irrelevant, the important part being that it happens server side, and not client side. As for CSS media queries, [`Style sheets with media queries attached to their <link> tags will still download even if their media queries would return false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). But yes, in general the server can't know what files are actually going to be requested as Tulains Córdova's `wget` example points out.

Answer (score 9):

Your question seems to assume that all of these resources are coming from the same source.  But that's not how the World Wide Web works.

The browser's prevailing (and correct) assumption is that resources can come from anywhere, and in fact they often do.  This is why we can stitch together web pages from many different resources, and have them appear as if they are a single document.

Javascript files are often served up from CDN's. Sourcing them from a CDN has certain technical advantages, like high performance and availability.  Browser caching takes care of any remaining problems.

Comment: Yes I thought about CDNs, but thought this could be good for local resources

Comment: The prevailing assumption still applies.  Resources can come from anywhere.  You can have relative URLs like  `..\somefile.js` indicating a local resource, but the browser still has to parse the page to discover that information.

Answer (score 6):

#### Caching

By sending them separately, a web browser can just cache the CSS and Javascript files, and reuse them when another page calls for the same file, skipping additional requests. If they're merged into the HTML file by the server, then the browser just sees a new unique file each time, and thus has to download the same CSS and Javascript content each time.

#### CSS and JS might not be wanted at all

As [Tulains Córdova](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/327592/why-dont-servers-deliver-js-and-css-at-the-same-time-as-html#comment695704_327592) pointed out in the comments, there are programs that can be and are used to download HTML files, but which will not request any linked CSS or Javascript files (and cannot, since they can't parse HTML).

Additionally, some browsers [won't request the Javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401947/3342206) when Javascript is disabled.